# Scale a div without changing the size and position of its child elements

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains some elements like `h` and `p` tags. How can I scale just the wrapper `div`, not inner elements?

```
 <div class="wrapper" style="padding:50px; transform:scale(1.1)">
      <h2>title</h2>
      <p>description</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by scale the wrapper? in case you want to increase the size of the wrapper you can just provide the width and height properties.

Comment: What should the result look like? Everything inside the div should behave as if the div wasn't scaled at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544645/css3-scale-transform-on-parent-div-but-keeping-constant-size-in-some-of-the-asso#answer-15545867

Comment: @Rahul I think I'm gonna add my answer in that topic you linked…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent the child elements to be scaled if you apply the `transform` on your `wrapper`.

⋅
⋅
⋅

But you can use a CSS variable to store your scale factor, and then use `calc` to calculate (better than doing it manually) and apply the inverse scale for the child elements:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 0 20px;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
  background: #ddd;
}

.wrapper > * {
  transform: scale(calc(1/var(--scale)));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 1">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 1.2">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 0.8">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Another way of doing it would be to style and scale your wrapper as a pseudo-element. That way, there is no element inside the pseudo-element, so nothing scales:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 1">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 1.2">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--scale: 0.8">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: important note: all child need to be at least inline-block as transform won't work with inline element .. I would probably consider a sub container to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hacky way of doing it - but it should give you what you're looking for. I've included a normal version and a scaled version to show the difference.

Effectively the scale of the child elements is 1 divided by the scale of the wrapper element (so for a transform:scale of 1.1 for example, the child elements would have a scale of 0.90909090909).

That being said, Takit's answer is better in that you don't have to calculate the inverse scale manually.

```css
.wrapper {
padding:50px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
}

.scaled {
transform:scale(1.2);
}

.scaled > * {
transform:scale(0.83333333333);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <h2>title</h2>
      <p>description</p>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="wrapper scaled">
      <h2>title</h2>
      <p>description</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check it:-

```css
 :root{
 --scaleVar:2;
 }
.wrapper.scaled {
  padding: 0 20px;
  transform: scale(var(--scaleVar));
  background: #ddd;
}

.wrapper.scaled * {
  transform: scale(calc(1/var(--scaleVar)));
}sform:scale(0.83333333333);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <h2>title</h2>
      <p>description</p>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="wrapper scaled">
      <h2>title</h2>
      <p>description</p>
 </div>
```