# Is it possible to keep child size when parent is scaled in svelte?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, svelte-transition

So I have an element that has a custom out transition, exactly this one:

```
export function rightScaleOut(node, options) {
  let nodeTransform = node.style.transform;
  return {
    delay: options.delay,
    duration: options.duration,
    easing: options.easing,
    css: (t) =>
      `transform: ${nodeTransform} scaleX(${t}); transform-origin: top right;`,
  };
}
```

Here's how I applied it to my element:

```
{#if show}
    <div
      out:rightScaleOut={{
        delay: 150,
        duration: 400,
        easing: sineInOut,
      }}
      data-title="picture portfolio"
      data-scroll-speed="1"
    >
      <img
        on:click={transition}
        on:keydown={transition}
        src="pictures/portfolioPicture/landing.png"
        alt="photography portfolio landing"
      />
    </div>
{#/if}
```

So the problem that I have is that when the `div` is getting out the element scale with him but I want the child to keep its original size.

I already checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544645/css3-scale-transform-on-parent-div-but-keeping-constant-size-in-some-of-the-asso) but it didn't help.

Comment: You mean like this? https://svelte.dev/repl/b53a2bb4eef2400b9206e0f33f37a26c?version=3.55.1

Comment: It's absolutely perfect thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your linked question, the size of the child can be kept constant by scaling it by `1 / factor` of the parent. This can be achieved with an additional custom transition on the image element

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b53a2bb4eef2400b9206e0f33f37a26c?version=3.55.1)

```
function rightScaleOutInverse(node, options) {
        let nodeTransform = node.style.transform;
        return {
            delay: options.delay,
            duration: options.duration,
            easing: options.easing,
            css: (t) =>
            `transform: ${nodeTransform} scaleX(${1/t}); transform-origin: top left;`,
        };
    }
```